# Show that the the linear map $I-L$ is invertible where $L:V \rightarrow V$ and $L^3 = 0$. Find the invertible matrix in terms of a polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map such that $L^3 = 0$ (i.e. $L^3$ is the zero matrix).  Show that $I-L$ is invertible and find $(I-L)^{-1}$ in terms of a polynomial of $L$.

This question is giving me fits.  How do I show this?  Furthermore, how do I find the invertible matrix in terms of a polynomial of $L$?  I know, by the Invertible Matrix Theorem, that the following are equivalent for an $n \times n$ square matrix:

- A is an invertible matrix
- A is row equivalent to the $n \times n$ identity matrix
- A has n pivot positions.
- $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution.
- The columns of A form a linearly independent set.
- The linear transformation $x \rightarrow Ax$ is one-to-one.
- The columns of A span $\mathbb{R}^n$
- The linear transformation $x \rightarrow Ax$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- There is an $n \times n$ matrix $C$ such that $CA=I$.
- There is an $n \times n$ matrix $D$ such that $AD=I$.
- $A^T$ is an invertible matrix.

and so on.

New to linear algebra.  Usually I can give a bit more in my questions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you could imagine that everything is a real number (it's not) do you know the power series for $(1-x)^{-1}$?  What does this look like if $x^3=0$?

Comment: Have you tried expanding $(I-L)^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

$L^k = 0, \; k \ge 1; \tag 1$

then consider the identity, which holds for any $m \ge 1$,

$L^m - I = (L - I)(\displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} L^j) = (L - I)(L^{m - 1} + L^{m - 2} + \ldots L + I); \tag 2$

this equation may easily be proved (by induction on $m$ if you like), and is quite likely familiar to the reader either from high-school algebra or the study of roots of unity in field theory.  Be that as it may, with (1) in place we see that (2) becomes, with $m = k$,

$-I = (L - I)(L^{k - 1} + L^{k - 2} + L + I), \tag 3$

which shows that $I - L$ is invertible with inverse

$(I - L)^{-1} = L^{k - 1} + L^{k - 2} + L + I. \tag 4$

The particular case at hand may be resolved by taking $k = 3$.

Comment: I don't see how you are getting from (2) to (3).  $L^{m}-I = (L-I)(L^{m-1}+L^{m-2}+...L+I)$ implies $-I =  (L-I)(L^{m-1}+L^{m-2}+...L+I)-L^m$.  How does this simplify to equation 4 (or am I just that tired and I'm being really dense)?

Comment: That is $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ which implies $-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)-x^3$

Comment: @IdleMathGuy:  notice that (3) is a *special case* of the general formula (2) with $m = k$ such that (1) holds, that is, $L^k = 0$.  If you multiply (3) by $-1$, you get $I = (I - L)(L^{k - 1} + \ldots + I)$, which shows that $(I - L)^{-1} = L^{k  - 1} + \ldots + I$.  Does this help?

Comment: @IdleMathGuy:  also, if $x^3 = 0$ then you get $-1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x  + 1)$ etc.

Comment: Perfectly.  Why is math so hard, Robert?  I study so hard, but sometimes, nothing.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @IdleMathGuy:  Glad to help out.  Math, like music, takes a *lot* of practice.  And I think sometimes academic institutions push too much on students too fast, so that they don't really learn in depth.  But it comes with time.  By the way, if you really found my answer helpful, you might consider that big phat ol' green check mark!  Cheers!